# How to detect attribute change in angular 2?

Tags: angular

Given the following code:

Parent component:

```
<my-cmp readonly></my-cmp>
```

Child component:

```
...
constructor(@Attribute('readonly') readonly) {
    this._readonly = readonly !== null ? 1 : 0;
  }
...
```

How do I detect changes to the readonly attribute?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Input()
set readonly(val) {
 if(val === '') {
  console.log('set');
 } else {
  console.log('removed'); 
}
```

Comment: Shoudn't it be `==` or `===`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, only on my phone.

Comment: I know how to do it with input variables. I just want to use plain attributes. I guess that's the @Attribute decorator is for. And ... I don't understand why someone downvoted you.

Comment: `@Attribute()` is only a one-time action. There is no way to get changes after the component was created. AFAIR. inputs work with attributes as well, I'm not absolutely sure if changes cause the settet being called again, but I think so.